# What is the correct address for loading spiffsimg file

Tags: lua, esp8266, firmware, nodemcu, flash-memory

I have used spiffsimg to create a single file containing multiple lua files:

```
# ./spiffsimg -f lua.img -c 262144 -r lua.script
f   4227 init.lua
f    413 cfg.lua
f   2233 setupWifi.lua
f   7498 configServer.lua
f    558 cfgForm.htm
f   4255 setupConfig.lua
f  14192 main.lua
#
```

I then use esptool.py to flash the NodeMCU firmware and the file containing the lua files to the esp8266 (NodeMCU dev kit):

```
c:\esptool-master>c:\Python27\python esptool.py -p COM7 write_flash -fs 32m -fm dio 0x00000 nodemcu-dev-9-modules-2016-07-18-12-06-36-integer.bin 0x78000 lua.img
esptool.py v1.0.2-dev
Connecting...
Running Cesanta flasher stub...
Flash params set to 0x0240
Writing 446464 @ 0x0... 446464 (100 %)
Wrote 446464 bytes at 0x0 in 38.9 seconds (91.9 kbit/s)...
Writing 262144 @ 0x78000... 262144 (100 %)
Wrote 262144 bytes at 0x78000 in 22.8 seconds (91.9 kbit/s)...
Leaving...
```

I then run ESPLorer to check the status and get:

```
PORT OPEN 115200

Communication with MCU..Got answer! AutoDetect firmware...

Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received.


NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: dev
    commit: b21b3e08aad633ccfd5fd29066400a06bb699ae2
    SSL: true
    modules: file,gpio,http,net,node,rtctime,tmr,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-07-18 12:05
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4(baaeaebb)
lua: cannot open init.lua
> 
----------------------------
No files found.
----------------------------
> 
Total : 3455015 bytes
Used  : 0 bytes
Remain: 3455015 bytes
```

The NodeMCU firmware flashed correctly, but the lua files can't be located.

I have tried flashing to other locations (0x84000, 0x7c000), but I am just guessing at these locations based on reading threads on github.

I used the NodeMCU file.fscfg() routine to get the flash address and size. If I only flash the NodeMCU firmware I get the following:

```
print (file.fscfg())
524288  3653632
```

534288 is 0x80000, so I tried flashing only the spiffsimg file (lua.img) to 0x8000, then ran the same print statement and got:

```
print (file.fscfg())
786432  3391488
```

The flash address incremented by the exact number of bytes in the lua.img - which I don't understand, why would the flash address change? Is the first number returned by file.fscfg not the starting flash address, but the ending flash address?

What is the correct address for flashing an image file, contain lua files, that was created by spiffsimg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of spiffsimg found [here](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/master/tools/spiffsimg) will provide the correct address for flashing an image file that contains lua files.

Do not use [this](https://github.com/DiUS/spiffsimg) version of spiffsimg as it is out of date.

To install the spiffsimg utility, you need to download and install the entire nodemcu-firmware package (into a linux environment, use make to install - note: make on my debian linux box generated an error, but i was able to go to the ../tools/spiffsimg subdirectory and run make on the Makefile found in that directory to create the utility).

The spiffsimg instructions found [here](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/docs/en/spiffs.md) are quite clear, with one exception: the file name you specify, with the -f parameter, needs to include the characters %x.  The %x will be replaced with the address that the image file should be flashed to.

For example, the command

> spiffsimage -f %x-luaFiles.img -S 4MB -U 465783 -r lua.script

will create a file, in the local directory, with a name like:  80000-luaFiles.img.  Which means you should install that image file at address 0x80000 on the ESP8266.

Comment: From time to time we rebaseline spiffs and it is essential that you use a spiffsimg version that matches your NodeMCU firmware's spiffs version.  The safest way to do this is as the posters suggest and use the version included in the software distro for the version of NodeMCU that you have flashed onto your ESPs

Answer (score -1):

I've never done that myself but I'm reasonably confident the correct answer can be extracted from [the docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/spiffs/).

> `-f` specifies the filename for the disk image. '%x' will be replaced
>   by the calculated offset of the file system.

And a bit further down

> The disk image file is placed into the `bin` directory and it is named
>   `0x<offset>-<size>.bin` where the offset is the location where it
>   should be flashed, and the size is the size of the flash part.

However, there's a slight mismatch between the two statements. We may have a bug in the docs. If "'%x' will be replaced..." then I'd expected the final name won't contain `0x` anymore.

Furthermore, it is possible to define a fixed SPIFFS position when you build the firmware.

> `#define SPIFFS_FIXED_LOCATION       0x100000`
>
> This specifies that the SPIFFS filesystem starts at 1Mb from the start of the flash. Unless
>   otherwise specified, it will run to the end of the flash (excluding
>   the 16k of space reserved by the SDK).

Comment: -f specifies the filename that spiffsimg creates, and it creates it in the local directory (wherever you run spiffsimg from). There is no bin directory in the spiffsimg-master directory (created by unzipping the spiffsimg-master.zip file). I manually created a local bin directory and ran spiffsimg again, but no files were created in the bin directory. I only get the file specified by the -f parameter.

Comment: I think [those docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/spiffs/) are out of date.  I tried using the -S and -U parameters instead of specifying the image size (using the -c parameter) and spiffsimg returned an "Invalid Option" error message.

Comment: I have been using this version of [spiffsimg](https://github.com/DiUS/spiffsimg).  Is there another version I should be using instead?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan for all the trouble. Triggered by your question I experimented with `spiffsimg` myself for the first time. A few things seem broken (at least to me) and I'll file an issue for that on GitHub. I've been using the one version we keep in the [firmware `tools` directory](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/master/tools/spiffsimg).

Comment: Is there a way to download all of the required source to build spiffsimg from the nodemcu-firmware/tools directory on github?  I couldn't locate a "spiffsimg" pkg.  Do i need to go through the source code and locate & download the required files? (I am a github noobie, so i am thinking i am missing something regarding downloading/building packages like spiffsimg)